# What format is this?

Tags: terminology, computer-science

I was given a snippet and can't seem to parse it myself, what's the name of this format and is there a tool that will render it like latex or mathML like this site does?

```
Sum_{n,k} T(n,k) x^2/n! y^k = 1+ln(Sum((4+y)^binomial(n, 2)*x^n/n!, n=0..infinity))
```

Comment: It looks like Maple code, but it isn't. The sum at the end renders as a sum in interactive Maple, but the binomial just looks like binomial(n,2). The beginning looks like LaTeX. Notice the notations for summation aren't consistent. My guess would be it's pseudocode. Where did it come from?

Comment: @MattSamuel https://oeis.org/A062734

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain it's just pseudocode. If you were to make it pretty, it would look like
$$\sum_{n,k}\frac{T(n,k)x^2y^k}{n!}=1+\ln\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(4+y)^{\binom{n}{2}}x^n}{n!}}\right)$$
This is the exponential generating function for the sequence. The formula that is displayed on the site is actually
$$\sum_{n,k}\frac{T(n,k)x^ny^k}{n!}=1+\ln\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(4+y)^{\binom{n}{2}}x^n}{n!}}\right)$$

Comment: Sorry, what's `T`?

Comment: @Moshe It's the sequence being displayed on the site. This is the exponential generating function for the sequence, sort of. I think there's probably a typo in it, where the $x^2$ should be $x^n$.

Comment: Still not following what `T` is, also does it help that there's this too?: `nn=6; s=Sum[(1+y)^Binomial[n, 2] x^n/n!, {n, 0, nn}]; Range[0, nn]!CoefficientList[Series[Log[ s]+1, {x, 0, nn}], {x, y}]//Grid  (* returns triangle indexed at n = 0, Geoffrey Critzer, Oct 07 2012 *)`

Comment: @Moshe I recommend you read the title of the sequence, it should make it clear what $T(n,k)$ is.

Comment: ok so `T(n,k)` is what we're trying to solve, so what's it doing as part of the equation? Also what are `x` and `y` then? Can you plug it in to the problem of `T(6, 13)`?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function. The coefficient of $x^ny^k$ on the right hand side is equal to $\dfrac{T(n,k)}{n!}$.

Comment: Ok, but how do you see where it converges and how does it always converge unto an interger (seeing as we take the log of a summation)? Would you be able to plug it into a real example like `T(6,13)` or `T(7,12)` ?

Comment: @Moshe for this one please read the Wikipedia article. A generating function is simply a way to express the sequence. You never plug numbers into it so convergence is not an issue. To expand the right hand side you'd plug the infinite series into the series for $\ln(1+x)$.

Comment: Ok I read that page and I'm still confused (sorry). We take the coefficient of the `n` term for `x` and the then we plug it into the equation `1 + ln(4 + y(n|2)) / n!` but what is y? is that just what `k` is?

Comment: @Moshe The series for $\ln(1+x)$ is $x-x^2/2+x^3/3\ldots$. If you were to take $\ln(1+x+x^3)$, you would expand $(x+x^3)-(x+x^3)^2/2+(x+x^3)^3/3\ldots$. We're doing the same thing, but with an infinite series.

Comment: The CoefficientList function and all the square brackets suggest that it's Mathematica code.